# Inconsistent results from Sharepoint 2010 Search when consumed by C# through SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint, search

I’ve written a user defined function in C# to consume the Sharepoint 2010 Search Service and make it available inside of my SQL Server 2008. Just searching works fine, but I want to be able to limit the results which directory it appears in. My base querytext is this:

```
SELECT top 10000 Path, HitHighlightedSummary FROM Scope() WHERE FREETEXT(DEFAULTPROPERTIES,'query')
```

If I expand the freetext to *query Path:directory* I get 176 results, whereas if I enter it into the default front end for Sharepoint Search, I get 1600.  Any thoughts as to why not?

In another example, I change the free text to *query Title:docTitle*, I get 2700 hits from my UDF, but only 170 from the Sharepoint front end.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user account the same? SharePoint does security filtering. It may also be trimming out results based on how you have setup your search service.

Comment: It is the same user account; there's only one. The normal results match up, it's only when I start adding modifiers. And I don't think it's security trimming, since it ends up adding more results (inaccurately) when I specify the Title.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the UI search is adding more/different modifiers to the query than your code is or the UI post-search processing is distorting the true number of search results.  I believe if you crank up the search related ULS categories to maximum levels you can see the actual queries that are being executed.  You might want to see what SharePoint is doing on your behalf when you are executing a query through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was to freetext the metadata in addition to the query:

```
SELECT top 10000 Path, HitHighlightedSummary FROM Scope()
WHERE FREETEXT(DEFAULTPROPERTIES,'query') AND FREETEXT(Path,'"directory"')
```